# Faithful locally free circle actions on a torus must be free?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, lie-groups, torus-action, torus

Is it true that every faithful and locally smooth action $S^1 \curvearrowright T^n$ is free?

I know such an action must induce an injection $\rho:\pi_1(S^1)\to\pi_1(T^n)$.
Another related question is: Is the image of $\rho$ saturated?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I assume that your action is smooth?  If so, it seems reasonable to guess that a smooth, faithful, locally free action has a "global section" -- a torus $T^{n-1}$ which meets all orbits, exactly once, transversely.  If there is a section, then the action should be conjugate to the action which rotates the first coordinate and fixes the others.

Comment: Yes I assume the action is smooth, but I am not sure whether there exists a transversal $T^{n-1}$. In fact, I am not sure $T^n/S^1$ is smooth.

Comment: This is true when $n\le 3$, I do not know about dimension 4 and higher.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Could you please briefly explain the argument for dim 3?

Comment: In a little while: It comes from the essential uniqueness of Seifert fibrations on 3-manifolds.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This follows from Theorem 9.3 (page 216) of the book "Compact tranformation groups" by Bredon (note that it is freely available online).

More is true: Any effective group action of a torus on a torus is free. The proof starts along the lines you mentioned via fundamental group considerations.

The result is originally due to Conner and Montgomery:

Conner, P. E., and Montgomery, DC. Transformation groups on a K(n, l), I. Michigan Math. J. 6 (1959), 405-412.

Comment: (I guess "effective" is an old synonym of "faithful".)